# Is the sentence, "What are the properties that are part of that", a little bit redundant?

Tags: meaning

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/T-HGdc8L-7w?t=1121)

> Try to encapsulate everything that has to do with that object
> into a class.
> **What are the properties that are part of that**?
> If you're making a rainbow, the properties
> are the colors, potentially.

The last "that" in the sentence in question refers to an unspecified object and the properties are part of the object.

Is it a little bit redundant? How about just first part?

> Try to encapsulate everything that has to do with that object into a class. **What are the properties**? If you're making a rainbow, the properties are the colors, potentially.

Comment: The **that** is awkward at best. The solution is to write: **What are its properties?**

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you. What the **that** is at worst?